# How to setText of JTextfield to a method with an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, methods, jtextarea

I have a class called ShoutBox, and there it has this array and this method:

```
   String messages[] = new String[10];
    //declare 10 arrays
    messages[0] = "Miley";
    messages[1] = "Katy";
    messages[2] = "Gaga";
    messages[3] = "Beyonce";
    messages[4] = "Taylor";
    messages[5] = "Missy";
    messages[6] = "Nicki";
    messages[7] = "Adele";
    messages[8] = "Rihanna";
    messages[9] = "Selena";

    String x = new ShoutBox().shoutOutCannedMessage(messages);
    System.out.println(x);

    public String shoutOutCannedMessage(String[] messages) {
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i+". "+messages[i]); 
    }

    System.out.print("Select a message: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    String message = messages[n];
    return message;
    }
```

And then I have a another class for GUI, how to I make that result appear in a JTextField when an action is perform?

```
    private void shoutOutMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent     evt) {                                                
  JTextArea.setText(????); 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to show the next phrase in the array in response to an event and not show all phrases all at once:

- Give your class an int index counter field, such as `private int shoutIndex` and initialize it to 0.
- On any pertinent event (such as in an ActionListener), increment that index, e.g., `shoutIndex++`
- Then make sure that the index is not larger than the length of the array using the remainder operator: `shoutIndex %= messages.length`
- Then get the corresponding item from the array using the index, `messages[shoutIndex]`, and use it to set the text of the JTextField.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I just start studying Java so I dont quite get what you mean :( .... so where do I declare the `private int shoutIndex ` variable? Isn't it the same as the `i` variable I have in the `shoutOutCannedMessage` above?

Comment: @VincentNg: you declare it as a field of your GUI, the class with the JTextField. And no it's not the same as `i` since a for loop will not work in this situation. I think that you're thinking of still using the for loop, and if so, you will want to read up more on event-driven programming to see why it is not appropriate.

Comment: Now im like lost :D I could declare the index and the increment it but when i do this `shoutIndex %= messages.length` the `messages` is not found...

Comment: @VincentNg: edit your post, show your latest code, preferably a [mcve], and let's see what's wrong